# changing two (unknown) dates inside a file using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to change a file with two (unknown) dates in format: YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-M-D to two different specified dates.
I can get one date change to work, or all dates changed to a single new date but I can't get the first encountered date to change to the 1st specified date, and the second to it's specified date. To illustrate:

```
Text file example:
text etc text
etc text 2015-09-04
text etc text
2015-8-2
```

I have the following script:

```
line = File.read("test.txt")

    new_contents = line.gsub(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/,'2016-10-10')

    puts new_contents

File.open("test.txt", "w") {|file| file << new_contents }
```

This works, but only for one date change.
I've tried just doubling up the script, and inserting a repeat of the above inside a "do loop" but it always changes both dates to the second specified date. Does anyone know where to look for an answer?

Also is there some way to specify either YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-M-D?

Update:
So I'm at this stage I have this code:

```
line = File.read("test.txt")
  new_contents = line.gsub(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{4}-\d{1}-\d{1})/) {$1 ? '2016-10-10':'9999-9-9'}
  puts new_contents
```

So nearly there but it seems to give random orders for the results. sometimes 2016-10-10 is first, sometimes second. Sometimes they are both 9999-9-9
It's a bit strange. I've tried reversing the values but the results are the same.

example to make it 100% clear (hopefully). Change dates to 2014-10-10 and 2014-11-11
ORGINAL:

```
lorem ipsum 1111-1-1 
lorem 1111-1-1
```

RESULT:

```
lorem ipsum 2014-10-10
lorem 2014-11-11
```

Example 2; Change dates to 2014-6-6 and 2014-11-11

ORIGINAL:

```
lorem ipsum 2014-10-10
lorem 2015-12-12
```

RESULT:

```
lorem ipsum 2014-6-6
lorem 2014-11-11
```

Comment: Did you try `/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/`?

Comment: Just remove the caret in your regex

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
line.gsub(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{4}-\d{1}-\d{1})/) {$1 ? '2016-10-10':'9999-9-9'}
```

Replace `'9999-9-9'` with your second date.

`gsub` accepts an optional block. It will replace any match with the result of that block.

**DESCRIPTION**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**DEMO**

Regex: http://rubular.com/r/KgSypeaKRu
Ruby code: https://code.hackerearth.com/caa872Q

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
print "2015-09-04".gsub(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{4}-\d{1}-\d{1})/) {$1 ? '2016-10-10':'9999-9-9'}
print "\n"
print "2015-7-7".gsub(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{4}-\d{1}-\d{1})/) {$1 ? '2016-10-10':'9999-9-9'}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2016-10-10
9999-9-9
```

**EDIT**
If you want to do custom replacements, here is an example:

```
lines.gsub(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{4}-\d{1}-\d{1})/) {
    if $1
       # YYYY-MM-DD
       # Do some replacements or not...
    else 
       # YYYY-M-D
       # Do other replacements...
    end
}
```

Please refer to the [`gsub` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) for any details.

Comment: Why not `/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/` as @stribizhev stated in his comment above. This is cleaner and more readable while maintaining the same functionality.

Comment: @Stephan where should I put the second date to be changed? with the '2016-10-10' ?  Like ''2016-10-10',''2016-11-11' ... I am fishing here but just to make sure everyone knows what I mean. The two dates (whatever they are) inside the text file have to change to two different specified dates in the script.

Comment: @engineersmnky The post didn't precise if a date like `YYYY-M-DD` or `YYYY-MM-D` is valid. @stribizhev's regex allows the two preceding forms.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. Almost there but there's some wierd results with the order. I've updated the question so you can see. Any ideas?

Comment: @Stephan won't those inputs be reasonable to assume given the second format e.g. 2015-10-1 or 2015-5-14?

Comment: @engineersmnky It depends on OP's inputs.

Comment: @boogiewonder Sorry, I didn't understand your point. Can you update your post with what you get and what you expect?

Comment: Hi @stephan. I updated the post. I added the code I'm using and the results I get. The script, based on the code you provided gives random results like: `2016-10-10
9999-9-9` and `9999-9-9
9999-9-9` and `2016-10-10
2016-10-10`. Different every time. I can't see why

Comment: @boogiewonder I'm sorry, I don't face your issue. Check this sample code: https://code.hackerearth.com/caa872Q

Comment: @Stephan It appears to be the date that's the problem. If the date is YYYY-M-D is causes a problem. Have a look at this: https://code.hackerearth.com/b61591B

Comment: @boogiewonder In the sample code you have posted, all dates formatted like 'YYYY-M-D' are replaced with '9999-9-9'. Where is the problem?

Comment: @stephan. Really sorry I was confusing the issue with last comment. Stackoverflow won't let me edit it so please ignore. This is the correct one. And refer to edit in the original question: The dates in the text/document can be either YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-M-D in any order, mixed, both the same, etc. Dates in the results must be replaced with 1) a first specified date in place of the first date original regardless of format, and 2) a second specified date regardless of format . It's not that EVERY date in format YYYY-M-D must be replaced with 9999-9-9 as per our example.

Comment: @boogiewonder Thanks for clearing your post. It's obvious now that you need custom replacements. See my edit for details.

Comment: Hi @Stephan I've been trying to get this to work but I'm at a loss. I don't know if it's my bad explanation. I just need the two dates (which can be YYYY-M-D or YYYY-MM-DD) to be changed to the two dates supplied (which are YYYY-M-D or YYYY-MM-DD, mixed, or both the same format).

Comment: @Stephan I figured it out with an expression that I'm sure looks sloppy but works for me. `new_contents = line.gsub(/(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})/, $second).sub(/(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})/, $first)` It basically gsubs both values to the second desired date and then subs the first value to the first desired date. Sloppy, I know, but that's all I need. Thanks very much for the regex expression